# Get Table CreateBy attribute from sys.tables

Tags: sql, t-sql

Is there a way to determine who created a user_table in the system tables? I see the create_date, modify_date, but do not see any pointers to who created or modified the tables.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This information isn't collected by default.

If the modification you are interested in is fairly recent you can get it from the [default trace](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10718/3690).

Failing that you might be able to determine it [from the transaction logs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10764/3690).

If you need this information ongoing you could create a DDL trigger to log schema changes.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'm surprised this information isn't saved by default. Seems valuable